# How to get the scroll position of webView

Tags: android

What I'm trying to do is to get my webView scroll position to when it's not on top, makes my header opaque. I've tried many things to get my scroll postion, like implents OnScrollListener and OnScrollChangedListener to my activity, but anyone works and I have no idea what to do. I have the following xml Layout in my activity

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        tools:context=".BrowserActivity"
         >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:background="@drawable/header" >

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/browser_title"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left_browser_title"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_right_browser_title"
                android:text="@string/empty"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_size_browser_title"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressUrl"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left_browser_progress"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"  />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left_browser_progress" 
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_navigation_left"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/forward"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_right_btn_download"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_navigation_right"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

         <WebView
             android:id="@+id/webView1"
             android:layout_below="@id/header"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

And the following Activity:

```
public class BrowserActivity extends Activity {

    String url;
    WebView webView;
    ProgressBar progressUrl;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_browser);

        progressUrl = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressUrl);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (extras != null) {

            metaDado = extras.getParcelable("metaDado");
        }

        TextView browserTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.browser_title);

        browserTitle.setText(metaDado.getName());

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

        if (metaDado.getType().equals(Constants.FULL)) {

            url = "file://" + Constants.DEST_PATH_PARENT + "/" + metaDado.getUuidInstituicao() + "/full/"
                    + metaDado.getOfflineUuid() + "/index.html";

        } else if (metaDado.getType().equals(Constants.PRES)) {

            url = "file://" + Constants.DEST_PATH_PARENT + "/" + metaDado.getUuidInstituicao() + "/pres/"
                    + metaDado.getOfflineUuid() + "/" + metaDado.getOfflineUuid() + "/index.html";
        }

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

                progressUrl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                progressUrl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        });

        webView.loadUrl(url);

    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Get the scroll position of a WebView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456861/android-get-the-scroll-position-of-a-webview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was to create a customized WebView that overrides a onScrollChanged method. The complete code you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17096527/how-to-instantiate-a-customized-webview)