# How to instantiate a Customized WebView

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a customized WebView that overrides a onScrollChanged method. But when I try to instantiate it I get the following error:

```
06-13 17:30:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(20366): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-13 17:30:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(20366): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{br.com.facilit.target.app.android/br.com.facilit.target.app.android.BrowserActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-13 17:30:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(20366):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
06-13 17:30:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(20366):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
06-13 17:30:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(20366):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
06-13 17:30:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(20366):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
06-13 17:30:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(20366):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-13 17:30:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(20366):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-13 17:30:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(20366):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-13 17:30:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(20366):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-13 17:30:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(20366):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-13 17:30:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(20366):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-13 17:30:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(20366):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-13 17:30:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(20366):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-13 17:30:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(20366): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-13 17:30:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(20366):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:81)
06-13 17:30:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(20366):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2696)
06-13 17:30:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(20366):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2744)
06-13 17:30:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(20366):    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:385)
06-13 17:30:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(20366):    at android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(AbsoluteLayout.java:52)
06-13 17:30:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(20366):    at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:1119)
06-13 17:30:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(20366):    at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:1102)
06-13 17:30:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(20366):    at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:1091)
06-13 17:30:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(20366):    at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:1081)
06-13 17:30:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(20366):    at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:1072)
06-13 17:30:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(20366):    at br.com.facilit.target.app.android.CustomizedWebView.<init>(CustomizedWebView.java:12)
06-13 17:30:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(20366):    at br.com.facilit.target.app.android.BrowserActivity.<init>(BrowserActivity.java:29)
06-13 17:30:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(20366):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
06-13 17:30:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(20366):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
06-13 17:30:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(20366):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
06-13 17:30:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(20366):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
06-13 17:30:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(20366):    ... 11 more
```

My customized webview code:

```
public class CustomizedWebView extends WebView {

    public CustomizedWebView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomizedWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {

        Log.d(Constants.BROWSER_ACTIVITY, "SCROLL CHANGED");
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
    }
}
```

How do I instantiate it:

```
public class BrowserActivity extends Activity {

    private MetaDados metaDado;
    String url;
    CustomizedWebView webView = new CustomizedWebView(this);
    ProgressBar progressUrl;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_browser);

        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        progressUrl = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressUrl);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (extras != null) {

            metaDado = extras.getParcelable("metaDado");
        }

        TextView browserTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.browser_title);

        browserTitle.setText(metaDado.getName());

        webView = (CustomizedWebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

        if (metaDado.getType().equals(Constants.FULL)) {

            url = "file://" + Constants.DEST_PATH_PARENT + "/" + metaDado.getUuidInstituicao() + "/full/"
                    + metaDado.getOfflineUuid() + "/index.html";

        } else if (metaDado.getType().equals(Constants.PRES)) {

            url = "file://" + Constants.DEST_PATH_PARENT + "/" + metaDado.getUuidInstituicao() + "/pres/"
                    + metaDado.getOfflineUuid() + "/" + metaDado.getOfflineUuid() + "/index.html";
        }

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

                progressUrl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                progressUrl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        });

        webView.loadUrl(url);

        addListeners();
    }

    private void addListeners() {

        Button goBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);

        Button goForward = (Button) findViewById(R.id.forward);

        goForward.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (webView.canGoForward()) {

                    webView.goForward();
                }
            }
        });

        goBack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (webView.canGoBack()) {

                    webView.goBack();
                }
            }
        });

    }

}
```

My xml file:

```
 <br.com.facilit.target.app.android.CustomizedWebView
     android:id="@+id/webView1"
     android:layout_below="@id/header"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:clickable="true"
     />
```

Comment: You are creating two instances of `CustomizedWebView`, and it's unclear why you are doing so. Where is the `new CustomizedWebView(this)` line in your code?

Comment: Post the code for your `BrowserActivity` class. That is required to understand what is going on. I suspect that you are trying to instantiate or find the `CustomizedWebView` in the constructor, before `onCreate` is called.

Comment: Can you guys see my edit?? I put all code that calls my customized WebView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove

```
CustomizedWebView webView = new CustomizedWebView(this);
```

As it appear to be unrequired, or move the `new CustomizedWebView(this)` to be called in `onCreate(savedInstanceState)`

Your context isn't fully initialised during the initialisation of the activity class