# How could I hide an EditText as I scroll in my Web View?

Tags: android, webview, android-edittext, scrollview

Whenever I scrolldown a page in my Web View it shows the an Edit Text and I'd like to hide that as I scroll. How could I go about doing that?

Comment: how about implementing a scroll listener for webview and hiding the edittext in scroll events & showing back when scroll finished? I guess it is possible check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14752523/how-to-make-a-scroll-listener-for-webview-in-android

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach to do that is to create your own WebView and override the scrollChanged method to capture the current position and hide your edit text when you want

```
@Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {

           // Put your logical to hide your edit Text here.

    }
```

You can find a good example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17096527/how-to-instantiate-a-customized-webview)